# After searching in database. In Angular grid, infinite scrolling is not working

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll, angular-grid

After database search using filter, scrolling is not working otherwise it works fine.  Below is my code for get data down method.

```
$scope.getDataDown = function() {
    var promise = $q.defer();
    $scope.lastPage++;
    if ($scope.data.length < $scope.total) {
    $http(getRequest()).success(function(data) {
        promise.resolve();
        $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.saveScrollPercentage();
        $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(data.content);
        $scope.total = data.total ? data.total : data.length;
        $scope.length = $scope.data.length;
        $scope.dataLength = $scope.data.length;
        $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded(false,
        $scope.lastPage < ($scope.total / $scope.pageSize));
      }).error(function(error) {
      $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded();
    });
  }
  return promise.promise;
};
```

Comment: Are you using ui-grid?

Comment: yes I am using ui-grid and sorry I first mentioned pagination but it's actually infinite scroll

Comment: and also one more thing after using filter, infinite scroll event is not getting fired as I understand by now.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using for server side filterting

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to do this right now, and server side filtering is working fine but what I checked that getDataDown function not getting fired after search

Comment: @DipParmar did you get any solution?

Comment: Not yet I was on leave. Now I will start to look in code.